# How to replicate Delicious-like clickable tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a list of possible tagwords, and I would like to show them below a text input field as clickable words. Once clicked, these words will disappear from below (would accept answer without this feature) and reappear in the text input field.

**Added bonus:** include the ability to delete the added tag from the input field (a la Delicious), but not as important as the above functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually the tags in delicous are not in the input field. It just looks like that. 
I'm working on a delicous like tag field. but still not ready to use. http://www.superbly.ch/?p=31

But you can find better variants here. 
http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/02/10/a-delicious-javascript-tagging-input-field/

Answer (score 2):

**My response to a misunderstood question:**

So bascially you want an auto-complete function for a tags-input? Classic case for AJAX! :)

First, you'll need a server side script wich will return all the tags that match the characters the user has already typed. This script could e.g. query a MySQL-database for all the tags. Performance tip: Make sure the `tag`-field is an index, so MySQL will find the tag faster. The response of the server could be a JSON or XML list of possible tags.

Then, you'll need a JavaScript which calls this server side script on every keystroke (maybe you want to add a little delay, so the server won't get overthrown by requests). The JavaScript then will parse the JSON or XML from the server and print it as HTML.

I think nobody here will code it for you (at least not for free), but I'm sure you'll be able to do this, as this is a pretty common task and google will sure help, too.

---

**Edit:** By the way, did you know my name's nobody? I actually wrote some example-code to get you started.

ajax.php:

```
// Add Databse-connection stuff right here

$q = strtolower ( $_GET['q'] );
if ( empty ( $q ) )
    die ( '' );

// Select all the tags that begin with the already-typed letters ($_GET["q"])
$query = "SELECT `tag` FROM `tags` WHERE `tag` LIKE ".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."_% LIMIT 10";
$did = mysql_query ( $query );
if ( !$did )
    die ( '' );

$tags = array ();
while ( $tag = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
    $tags[] = $tag[0];
}

// Yes, I actually didn't use any JSON or XML here, just a comma-seperated list
$ret = implode ( ",", $tags );

echo $ret;
```

autocomplete.js:

```
var tags_input = document.getElementById("tags");
var timeout = 500; // If the user doesn't type for this amount of miliseconds, the AJAX request gets sent. To protect the server a little bit. :)

var xhr;
var do_ajax = false; // Gets true after 500 ms of not typing

var tags = [];

tags_input.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if ( !e ) e = window.event;

    do_ajax = false;

    window.setTimeout ( function () {
        do_ajax = true;
        ajax_request();
    }, 500 );

};

function ajax_request () {
    var q = tags_input.value;
    if ( q == '' )
        return;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open ( 'GET', 'ajax.php?q='+q, true );
    xhr.send ( null );
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( xhr.responseText != '' ) {
                tags = xhr.responseText.split ( ',' );
                show_autocompletions();
            }
        }
    };
}

function show_autocompletions () {
    alert ( tags.join ( ', ' ) ); // you might want to generate some real HTML here
}
```

Table-structure for this example: The table's called `tag` and it contains the only field `tag`, which is a unique index. Make sure `tag` doesn't contain any commas.

Comment: andre, I hate to do this to you after you helped me so much -- I wasn't asking for autocomplete. I have a preset list of 10 tags which I want to list as clickable below an input field. when the user clicks the tag, the tag disappears and reappears in the text field above

Comment: ooh, well, my fault. I was pretty overenthusiastic. :D I think I will still let my example in there, in case someone else finds it helpful.